# How to install mysql workbench on linux debian 10 (Google Pixelbook)

Tags: mysql, debian, mysql-workbench, google-chrome-os, debian-buster

I am trying to install MySQL Workbench on my Google Pixelbook. It runs Linux debian 10 buster.

So I run these commands:

`sudo apt-get update`

and then

`sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench`

I get this error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: gdal-abi-2-1-2
                   Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libmysqlcppconn7v5 (>= 1.1.7) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: ttf-bitstream-vera but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: mysql-utilities but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install these dependencies it is a never-ending story of missing dependencies like described in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005179/unable-to-install-mysql-workbench-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts

I searched a lot on several forum for a solution but nothing works. Most solutions I found was for Ubuntu and not for Debian

FYI, at first I tried to install it by downloading and installing the following file `mysql-workbench-community_8.0.23-1ubuntu20.10_amd64.deb` and it didn't work.. Maybe it created some kind of conflict that prevents me from installing it with `apt` or `apt-get`

What are your thoughts dear community?

Comment: You ask this question on the wrong website, visit https://serverfault.com/ and i am sure someone can answer your question over there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask it there! https://serverfault.com/questions/1054038/how-to-install-mysql-workbench-on-linux-debian-10-google-pixelbook